# If I set up a home web server, will computers that use my wi-fi be vulnerable?

Tags: wifi, webserver

I'm interested in setting up a web server on an old laptop `L1`.  My plan is to connect that laptop to an Ethernet port on my router.  I also have another laptop `L2` accessing the router via wi-fi.  `L2` is running Windows 7; I haven't chosen an OS yet for `L1` but it will probably be a Linux distro.  If someone attacks my website and somehow gains control of `L1`, can they access `L2` as well?  I'm trying to figure out how I can use `L1` as a laboratory for security testing and web development without putting `L2` at risk.

Comment: So far I've found this discussion: http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2357883

Comment: Unless there's some extremely strong reason to set this up in your home network, I'd advise using digitalocean or AWS instead.

Comment: @penguat, yeah, it's looking like delegating network security to a professional is going to be easier.  I just had an old laptop and thought it would be fun to use it to host a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L2 is also vulnerable if everyone can access your home server using public IP (if you have one). As long as you set up a home server only using private IP (NAT), it will be accessible only to people who connected to your network, but including people who use your wi-fi since they are in a same router. If it's your only option, just make sure that your wi-fi is secure enough.

Another option to build a private home lab for security testing, you can use virtual machine, so you can test anything to your virtual machine without any risk.

Comment: I want to use L1 to serve a website over the internet; that would mean I'd need to have a public IP, right?

Comment: Fully accessible over the internet? Yes, you need a public IP to do that, means a total risk for your home network and anything connected to it if your home server is not secure enough. Or at least you can configure your router to use DMZ if it's supported, for a temporary public access while testing.

Comment: you can use DMZ on your router and expose the other machine to internet and also use a firewall on it to block all incoming connections except the ports you want to exploit

Answer (score 1):

If L1 becomes compromised then the attacker is inside your network, and yes any other device connected to the same network (be it via WiFi, Wired, whatever) is vulnerable to some sort of attack. What that attack may be is then dependent on what ports are open on L2, and what software versions it's using. But in general it's safe to assume that if L1 is compromised, L2 is also - at the very least even with no running services and everything fully patched, if an attacker is inside your network all your packets are going to be visible to them.

If you absolutely must have L1 visible to the internet, then depending on your router you may be able to give it a second subnet. For example, many routers now offer a "Guest Access" setting which uses a secondary network with a different password. Whether or not this would then allow you to host services would depend on your router.

If you know the IP address you're going to be attacking from, you could use a firewall to only allow that IP to access the web server?